# Identifiers not found?

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors

I keep getting errors in this really simple program and I can't figure out why.  Help!

```
//This program will calculate a theater's revenue from a specific movie.
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    const float APRICE = 6.00,
          float CPRICE = 3.00;

    int movieName,
        aSold,
        cSold,
        gRev,
        nRev,
        dFee;

    cout << "Movie title: ";
    getline(cin, movieName);
    cout << "Adult tickets sold: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> aSold;
    cout << "Child tickets sold: ";
    cin >> cSold;

    gRev = (aSold * APRICE) + (cSold * CPRICE);
    nRev = gRev/5.0;
    dFee = gRev - nRev;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Movie title:" << setw(48) << movieName << endl;
    cout << "Number of adult tickets sold:" << setw(31) << aSold << endl;
    cout << "Number of child tickets sold:" <<setw(31) << cSold << endl;
    cout << "Gross revenue:" << setw(36) << "$" << setw(10) << gRev << endl;
    cout << "Distributor fee:" << setw(34) << "$" << setw(10) << dFee << endl;
    cout << "Net revenue:" << setw(38) << "$" << setw(10) << nRev << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And here are the errors I'm getting:

```
 error C2062: type 'float' unexpected
 error C3861: 'getline': identifier not found
 error C2065: 'CPRICE' : undeclared identifier
```

I've included the necessary directories, I can't understand why this isn't working.

Comment: I'd suggest declaring only one variable per declaration; for example `... int aSold; <newline> int bSold; ...`.

Answer (score 6):

For your first error, I think that the problem is in this declaration:

```
 const float APRICE = 6.00,
       float CPRICE = 3.00;
```

In C++, to declare multiple constants in a line, you don't repeat the name of the type.  Instead, just write

```
 const float APRICE = 6.00,
             CPRICE = 3.00;
```

This should also fix your last error, which I believe is caused by the compiler getting confused that `CPRICE` is a constant because of the error in your declaration.

For the second error, to use `getline`, you need to

```
#include <string>
```

not just

```
#include <cstring>
```

Since the `getline` function is in `<string>` (the new C++ string header) and not `<cstring>` (the old-style C string header).

That said, I think you'll still get errors from this, because `movieName` is declared as an `int`.  Try defining it as a `std::string` instead.  You might also want to declare your other variables as `float`s, since they're storing real numbers.  More generally, I would suggest defining your variables as you need them, rather than all up at the top.

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for declaring as needed. A variable should always have the tightest scope possible, and be initialized immediately upon declaration.