# Getline error--"could not deduce template argument"

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, getline

This is a really simply program and I don't know what I've got wrong.  I've looked online and I haven't been able to find anything helpful.  There's something wrong with my getline(cin, movieName), but I don't know what.

```
//This program will calculate a theater's revenue from a specific movie.
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    const float APRICE = 6.00,
                CPRICE = 3.00;

    int movieName,
        aSold,
        cSold,
        gRev,
        nRev,
        dFee;

    cout << "Movie title: ";
    getline(cin, movieName);
    cout << "Adult tickets sold: ";
    cin.ignore();
    cin >> aSold;
    cout << "Child tickets sold: ";
    cin >> cSold;

    gRev = (aSold * APRICE) + (cSold * CPRICE);
    nRev = gRev/5.0;
    dFee = gRev - nRev;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
    cout << "Movie title:" << setw(48) << movieName << endl;
    cout << "Number of adult tickets sold:" << setw(31) << aSold << endl;
    cout << "Number of child tickets sold:" <<setw(31) << cSold << endl;
    cout << "Gross revenue:" << setw(36) << "$" << setw(10) << gRev << endl;
    cout << "Distributor fee:" << setw(34) << "$" << setw(10) << dFee << endl;
    cout << "Net revenue:" << setw(38) << "$" << setw(10) << nRev << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And here's the errors I'm getting:

```
 error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'int' see declaration of 'std::getline'

error C2780: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : expects 3 arguments - 2 provided
 see declaration of 'std::getline'

error C2784: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &' from 'int'
 see declaration of 'std::getline'

error C2780: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &std::getline(std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits> &&,std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &,const _Elem)' : expects 3 arguments - 2 provided
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\string(395) : see declaration of 'std::getline'
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `getline` requires a `std::string` (or some other type of `basic_string`) as its argument, and you're providing an `int`.  As I [mentioned in my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9307020/501557), you should switch the type of `movieName` to be a `std::string`.  You should also change the type of your other variables appropriately (they should probably be `float`s if you're multiplying other values by `float`s), and I'd suggest moving the definitions down to later in `main` where they're actually used.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I see is movieName is declared as an integer instead of a string or char array (C string). That seems to be the main issue causing multiple errors in regards to getline.